# Can't I import an Injectable class as service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I"m building an app with Ionic 2 and have come across a problem. Any help would much appreciated.

I am using a service called `plan-data.ts` to get and post data to a firebase database.The problem I'm running into is that when I try to import and declare the `plan-data.ts` file on a few specific components, it errors out. On the page below it is working fine!

```
    **DASHBOARD.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { PlanData } from '../../providers/plan-data/plan-data';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/dashboard/dashboard.html',
      providers: [PlanData]
    })
    export class DashboardPage {

      constructor(private navCTRL: NavController, public planData: PlanData){
        this.planData = planData;
        this.loadList();
      }
      ...
    }
```

But on this file, when I try to import and declare it as a `provider`, it fails with an error of: `Cannot read property 'parameters' of undefined`.

```
    **STOPWATCH.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { PlanData } from '../../providers/plan-data/plan-data';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/watch-calc/watch-calc.html',
      providers: [PlanData]
    })
    export class WatchCalcPage {

      constructor(private navCTRL: NavController, public planData: PlanData) {
        this.planData = planData;
      }
```

I can't seem to figure out what is different or wrong on the second page and can't seem to find anyone having this issue which means it's probably me no seeing something simple. And suggestions would be very helpful, thank you!

Comment: Is second example works fine without PlanData injection? If yes, please could you add PlanData service code to your question.

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from `WatchCalcPage`?  It could be a template error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using a service called plan-data.ts to get and post data to a
>   firebase database

Do you *intentionally* want to create a new instance of the `PlanData` class in each page? By adding it in the providers array of both `DashboardPage` and `WatchCalcPage`, a **different** instance will be created for each page.

In order to use the same instance in the entire app, you should include the `PlanData` class in the providers array of the top-most component like this:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  providers: [PlanData, ...]
})
export class MyApp { ... }
```

And then just include it in the constructor

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PlanData } from '../../providers/plan-data/plan-data';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/watch-calc/watch-calc.html'
})
export class WatchCalcPage {

  constructor(private navCTRL: NavController, public planData: PlanData) {
    // this.planData = planData; <- you don't need to do this; it's done automatically by typescript because it's included as a parameter in the constructor.
  }
```

Comment: Are you sure the answer has a relation to the question? How did you assume this is what he wanted?

Comment: You're right, I was going to add this as a comment, but it was too long and hard to understand that way so I added it as an answer. I'm not sure if this is what the user wants, but having different instances of a service that gets and posts data to a server seems not to be the best way to do it. Also, by changing the way the class is being used, the issue could be fixed... If the user says that this is not what he wants I'll delete the answer in order to avoid other SO users from getting confused :)

Comment: I hadn't realized that I was using two difference instances! I'm still pretty new programming and really new Ionic. With that suggestion I change my `app.ts` and then ran into a few more errors. But fixing those errors showed me the error in `plan-data.ts`! I was importing NavController for some reason, and it was breaking. 
Thanks for the input! Maybe not a direct answer, but it certainly got the job done.